# Java Install Error 1723

Tags: windows-7, installation, java, jre

I was working on a program in Eclipse. I went to run it, and ran into some 'unknown source' errors, so I tried to reinstall my java and ran into some annoying errors. First thing I ran into was an error saying that Z: is an invalid drive during the uninstall of the JRE.

I used to have a Z partition on my drive with some stuff installed to it, but that has since been changed. I tried again, and ran into a 1723 error, which from what I've found is a problem with the Windows Installer. I'm running Windows 7 and haven't found anything so I can reinstall it. I ran into the same 1723 error when trying to install java over top of the failed uninstall. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem on my Windows 7 box where I was trying to uninstall Java and do a clean install of a newer version.  Something got messed up and I would get the 1723 error message during the uninstall and attempted reinstall.  Here's information about how I was able to fix the problem, and maybe this will help you:

Look at the log files for the uninstall/reinstall.  On Windows 7 they can be found at `c:\users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\`

The `java_install.log`didn't show any extra information, but I had several `MSI#####` log files that contained error messages about the failed uninstall.  The message was: `Error 1723.There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A DLL required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor. Action UninstallJRE, entry: MSIUninstallJRE, library: C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\regutils.dll`

There was indeed no `regutils.dll` file, and not even the `bin`directory was there. So I copied over a `regutils.dll` file from another computer, ran the uninstaller, and it worked.  Then the new clean install of Java also worked.

So take a look at your logfiles and hopefully that will give you more detailed information about the 1723 error.

Comment: To complete this answer: These logfiles will be written into the path %USERS%\AppData\Local\Temp

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same situation and I could find another way to solve this issue.

I downloaded the offline version from JRE6 and did install this - with default preferences- first. After that I installed the offline JDK version, also with default preferences. When I got the a positiv feedback from installer, I deinstalled both versions and installed the pure JDK in a folder of my choice.